# WordPress jQuery empty input value for a custom field

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, custom-post-type

I'm trying to get the input value of a custom post field for a custom post type using JS without success. When inspecting the jQuery object, there's no value property.
The code works outside of WordPress and even works for a different input, the core WP title input field. The end goal is to use Ajax to check if value exists in the database.

Followed this example:
https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/metadata/custom-meta-boxes/#client-side-code

jQuery v3.4.1,
WP v6.3

The custom meta box input field HTML:

```
<input type="url" name="myprefix-item-url" id="myprefix-item-url" value="" style="width: 100%;">
```

Core WP title input field HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="post_title" size="30" value="" id="title" spellcheck="true" autocomplete="off">
```

JS:

```
// wp-content/plugins/my-plugin/admin/meta-boxes/js/admin.js

(function ($, window, document) {
    'use strict';
    // execute when the DOM is ready
    $(document).ready(function () {
        // NOTE: works for #title
        $('#myprefix-item-url').on('change', function () {
            const userInput = $(this).val();
            console.log('input:', userInput);
        });
    });
}(jQuery, window, document));
```

PHP:

```
// wp-contents/plugins/my-plugin/my-plugin.php

function myprefix_meta_box_scripts() {
    // get current admin screen, or null
    $screen = get_current_screen();
    // verify admin screen object
    if (is_object($screen)) {
        // enqueue only for specific post types
        if (in_array($screen->post_type, ['myprefix_item'])) {
            // enqueue script
            wp_enqueue_script('myprefix_meta_box_script', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . 'admin/meta-boxes/js/admin.js', ['jquery']);
            // localize script, create a custom js object
            wp_localize_script(
                'myprefix_meta_box_script',
                'myprefix_meta_box_obj',
                [
                    'url' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php'),
                ]
            );
        }
    }
}
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'myprefix_meta_box_scripts');
```

Result in console:

```
input:
```

JsFiddle:

```js
(function ($, window, document) {
    'use strict';
    // execute when the DOM is ready
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#myprefix-item-url').on('change', function () {
            const userInput = $(this).val();
            console.log('url:', userInput);
        });
    });
}(jQuery, window, document));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="url" name="myprefix-item-url" id="myprefix-item-url" value="" style="width: 100%;">
```

Please help me to find out what's going on

Comment: Do you realize that the code snippet that you posted actually works?

Comment: @Klaassiek
"The code works outside of WordPress and even works for a different input, the core WP title input field."

Comment: So it works for other inputs based on a different id and it works in isolation with the same id - so there must be an issue with the id: `$('#myprefix-item-url')`    just before that line, add `console.log($('[id="myprefix-item-url"]').length)` - I'll hazard a guess that this will give either 0 or >1 (ie not ===1)

Comment: So, at the time the event handler initiates, you either have multiple inputs with the same ID and you're assigning the event handler to the wrong one so it "doesn't work" - or the element doesn't exist at that time.  If it does exist later (I'd assume it does otherwise where do you get the ID from) then you'll need to add your event handler later, after the element is generated.   Alternatively, use *event delegation*  - change `$("#id").on("change", function...` to `$(document).on("change", "#id", function...`.

Comment: @freedomn-m Logging the length gives 2. Also checking the source code of the page revealed that the input is wrapped within a div with the same ID. Indeed I have multiple elements with the same ID. I changed $('#myprefix-item-url') to $('#myprefix-item-url input') to target the correct element and it works now. Thank you.

Comment: @freedomn-m Sorry, console log of length gives 2 and not 0. Edited the previous comment.

Comment: This means you have **two** elements with the same ID.   `$("#id")` will only affect one of them.  IDs should (must) be unique within an HTML page to use `#` selector.

Comment: *and it works now* - glad you got it sorted.